# Login/out react routing and expressjs routing

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, reactjs, react-router

What im trying to do is Have a Log In page, a Sign up page. The login and signup work fine, they just perform whatever was written in express using passport. However what I want to do is make a route '/dashboard'. I did so and it's just a dashboard component made up of other components like a navbar and body/content. How do I write it in react router in such a way that it only allows me to access the route /dashboard if the user is authenticated. In express I would write a function like this :

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
   //if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
   if (req.isAuthenticated())
      return next(); //cuz we want to move on incase we're stuck here

   //if they arent redirect them to the home page
   res.redirect('/');
}
```

However I didn't even write in the dashboard route in express. I only did it in react-router. My component hierarchy is like this right now

```
<App/>
  <Dashboard/>
     <NavBar/>
         <NavMenu/>
      <Body/>
<Login/>
<Signup/>
<About/>
```

And my routing is like this :

```
<Route>
 <Route name ="signup" path="/signup" handler={Signup} />
 <Route name ="login" path="/" handler={Login} />
 <Route name ="app" path="/dashboard" handler={App} >
  <Route name ="logout" path="/logout" handler={NavMenu} />
 </Route>
</Route>
```

I don't understand if i'm grasping the concept right, but from what the webpage is displaying it doesn't seem like it. So basically at localhost:3000/ comes up the log in page, and I can toggle between that and the signup page completely fine, when the log in button is hit it uses express to login (it can use react-router to do it as well correct?), on success it goes to /dashboard (res.redirect('/dashboard') in express). It also seems as routes handled by react router has that single page app feel, whereas express it feels like i'm going to a new webpage (I'm guessing that happens because of react-router just changing the url and rendering the component we want?). In my NavMenu component I link the logout button Logout however the url changes to localhost:3000/logout and nothing happens.

Comment: I got rid of the <Route name ="logout"...> for now and let the server handle it by doing req.logout, and then res.redirect. However how would I do this in the front end where if user isnt logged it doesn't allow them to access the remaining react-router routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I nested it under login so to get to dashboard and it's routehandler it has to go through the login.

```
<Login>
 <App>
   <RouteHandler>
     <dashboard../>
     <data../>
     <etc../>
```